# Where can I go to find importers?

Tags: beans

I am from Ethiopia. I have a Coffee Export License from Ethiopia for the World market. How can I go about getting buyers? Where is the best place to find potential importers of my coffee?

Comment: Do you have a local chamber of commerce or something like that? You could ask if they have any contacts.

Answer (score 3):

The first recommendation would be to go to a **Chamber of Commerce or a Board of Trade locally** and to make a request to help with the contacts of potential importers.

Quick googling directed me to website of the Chamber of Commerce in Ethiopia: http://www.ethiopianchamber.com/

The Government of Ethiopia also hosted [World Coffee Conference](http://icocoffeeorg.tumblr.com/post/143372443370/videos-from-the-4th-world-coffee-conference-now), so you may find additional information on event, and may be some useful contacts to start with.

The second option would be **to get in touch with biggest Coffee Associations or to participate in coffee conferences/shows**:

- [The International Coffee Organization (ICO)](http://www.ico.org/)
- [Specialty Coffee Association of America (SCAA)](http://scaa.org/)
- [Specialty Coffee Association of Europe (SCAE)](http://scae.com/)
- Different coffee shows, conferences and festivals ([here's the calendar and links with additional information can be found](http://www.roastmagazine.com/currentissue/currentissue/tradeshowcal.html))

Answer (score 2):

Go to any coffee trade show in the US or Europe.  I would recommend the [Specialty Coffee Association of America](http://scaa.org/) or the [Specialty Coffee Association of Europe](http://scae.com/). Other options are: CoffeeFest, CoffeeCon, etc. An Internet search for coffee conferences really would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reaching out to distribution companies directly. Search as if you were a coffee roaster trying to buy beans and you'll find the companies that are selling in bulk.

I work at a coffee company where we work directly (and almost exclusively) with growers, but most companies are happy to deal with resellers.